# Change resolution in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, resolution

I just installed elementary OS 0.3.1 in a VirtualBox 4.3.12 (using MacOS X 10.9.5 as a host), installed the guest additions (I had to mount the CD manually and execute the `.run` script manually) but the screen resolution is still at 640x400. The vbox kernel module seems to be loaded:

```
 johannes@johannes-VirtualBox:~$ lsmod | grep vbox
 vboxguest             249856  5
```

Am I missing something obvious? Should I maybe upgrade my VirtualBox host software?

Comment: I don't think it will help, but what's stopping you from using VirtualBox 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to VirtualBox 5 and reinstalling the guest additions and rebooting elementary OS actually solved the problem.